# Unable to override delegate property in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to make a `StudentPickerController` similar to `ImagePickerController`:

```
class StudentPickerController: UINavigationController, NSCoding {
    unowned(unsafe) var delegate: protocol<StudentPickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?
}

@objc protocol StudentPickerControllerDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    optional func studentPickerControllerDidFinishPickingStudent(student: Student)
    optional func studentPickerControllerDidCancel()
}
```

This however gives me:

```
`Property 'delegate' with the type 'protocol<StudentPickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?' cannot override a property with type 'UINavigationControllerDelegate?'`
```

When looking at the swift file for `UIImagePickerController` you can see:

```
class UIImagePickerController : UINavigationController, NSCoding {    
    unowned(unsafe) var delegate: protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>?
}

protocol UIImagePickerControllerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    optional func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])
    optional func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
}
```

**How is `UIImagePickerController` able to override `delegate` but my class is not?**

*I understand that I could simply rename my property to avoid this but I would like to know how `UIImagePickerController` is able to accomplish this.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So my question is how is ImagePickerController able to override delegate but my class is not?

`UIImagePickerController` is bridged from Objective-C, where it is possible to override properties.  So if you really-really need this then you might want to implement `StudentPickerController` in Objective-C and use it's bridged version in Swift code.

If stay in Swift, what you can do is something like:

```
class StudentPickerController: UINavigationController {
    private var studentDelegate: StudentPickerControllerDelegate?
    override var delegate: UINavigationControllerDelegate? {
        didSet { studentDelegate = delegate as? StudentPickerControllerDelegate }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a delegate property for a class that already has one. You can't define a new delegate property with the same name.

I believe you can derive your `StudentPickerControllerDelegate` from `UINavigationControllerDelegate` and then assign the navigationController.delegate to your object that conforms to `StudentPickerControllerDelegate`. Or you can use a different property name for your delegate.

Comment: I understand I could just change the name but how is `UIImagePickerController` able to override this without the need to use a different name?